# Can I access Flutter GetXController properties with variable name?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I hope you have a great day.

I wonder can I access GetXcontroller property with variable

For example:

**my_controller.dart**

```
class MyController extends GexController {
  var isDocumentX = false.obs 
}
```

**ui_page.dart**

```
final myContr = Get.put(MyController());

// I want to access like this

myContr.{dynamic}.value
```

Value of dynamic is from api and the value is the same with controller property in this example is isDocumentX.

I hope my question and example is clear enough to understand

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think dynamic access is not possible with variable but you should try with Map

```
  Map<String, dynamic> myDocuments = <String, dynamic>{
    isDocumentX : false,
  }.obs;
```

And access like below

```
myContr.{myDocuments[<dynamic_api_key>]}.value
```